# make a function that takes in two arrays. Add all the numbers in arr1 & arr2. If the sum of arr1 is equal to arr2 return true. False if not

Tags: javascript

So, I know how to add up the integers in my given array but I am totally stumped on the comparison logic and returning the bool. Recursion or reduce can be used. It doesn't really matter.

This is the last quiz I have to take for my class before I can go on break

```
function isBalanced(arr1, arr2){
  arr1.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  arr2.reduce((a, b) => {
    return a + b;
  }, 0);
  return arr1 === arr2;
}
```

I'm getting expected false to be true in my tests.

Comment: well, if you know how to sum all the array elements, you probably miss only `return sum1 == sum2`?...

Comment: I think you are missing the point of stackoverflow. It is not here so others can do your work for you. Please update your question to include your attempt and we will be able to assist.

Comment: @berto99 Okay cool, i will try this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array#reduce` to find the sum of an array. Then, just compare the sums of the two arrays.

```js
function sum(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
}
function sumEqual(arr1, arr2) {
  return sum(arr1) === sum(arr2);
}
console.log(sumEqual([1, 3, 2], [3, 2, 1]));
```

Comment: I reattempted with what you suggested but I'm still receiving a false expected to be true. Do you mind taking a loot at what I did wrong?

Comment: @sggk Could you provide a [mre]?

Comment: @sggk Did you use the code in my example?

Comment: @sggk If you use the same idea as the code in my example, it will work. If you want it in one line, use `return arr1.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0)===arr2.reduce((a,b)=>a+b,0);`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let array_1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
let array_2 = [10,5];

const check_if_equal = (arr_1, arr_2)=> arr_1.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0) === arr_2.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

console.log(check_if_equal(array_1, array_2));
```

Comment: Appreciate the input!!